# Spark cluster - read/write on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop-yarn

I would like to read data from hadoop, process on spark, and wirte result on hadoop and elastic search. I have few worker nodes to do this.

Spark standalone cluster is sufficient? or Do I need to make hadoop cluster to use yarn or mesos?

If standalone cluster mode is sufficient, should jar file be set on all node unlike yarn, mesos mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can not write data in Hadoop or read data from Hadoop. It is HDFS (Component of Hadoop ecosystem) which is responsible for read/write of data. 
Now coming to your question

1. Yes, it possible to read data from HDFS and process it in spark engine and then write the output on HDFS.
2. YARN, mesos and spark standalone all are cluster managers and you can use any one of them to do management of resources in your cluster and it had nothing to do with hadoop. But since you want to read and write data from/to HDFS then you need to install HDFS on cluster and thus it is better to install hadoop on your all nodes that will also install HDFS on all nodes. Now whether you want to use YARN, mesos or spark standalone that is your choice all will work with HDFS I myself use spark standalone for cluster management.
3. It is not clear about which jar files you are talking to but I assume it will be of spark then yes you need to set the path for spark jar on each node so that there will be no contradiction in paths when spark run's.

Comment: Wrong question, good answer. thanks:) I decided to use yarn on system. If so, Is this able to write result output data on single hdfs, so it can be used for another input data?

Comment: Yes once written to hdfs it can be used as input in other map reduce job. But by single hdfs if you mean single output file then you need to take single reducer because each reducer create it's separate output file although all are saved in same directory. One more corner case is if your output file is too large then it will be splited in multiple output file however you can control that also by overriding RecordWriter. Output of the reduce task is typically written to a RecordWriter via TaskInputOutputContext.write(Object, Object).